# constexpr initializer_list raising an error: "expression must have a constant value -- reference or pointer to temporary with limited lifetime"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, constexpr, initializer-list

Here's the problem:

```
int main() 
{
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> my_ints {1, 2, 3};
}
```

I'm trying to compile the above with g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, version 8.1.0). But VS Code raises the following warning:

"expression must have a constant value -- reference or pointer to temporary with limited lifetime"

When I remove the `constexpr` specifier, that is, when I amend the code to

```
int main() 
{
    std::initializer_list<int> my_ints {1, 2, 3};
}
```

the error goes away, so it seems there's something wrong with declaring a `constexpr initializer_list`.

Yet according to this reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list), it should be perfectly fine to declare a `constexpr initializer_list`.

Can someone with deeper insight into the workings of `constexpr` and `initializer_list` explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6):

There's a clue to the cause of this problem over at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type std::initializer_list is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type const T.

and:

> Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length.

In other words, when you do this at local scope:

```
std::initializer_list<int> my_ints {1, 2, 3};
```

the compiler has to allocate (and initialise) `{1, 2, 3}` on the stack, so it can't be `constexpr`.

Fortunately, there's an easy workaround.  Just do:

```
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> my_ints {1, 2, 3};
```

Now the underlying array is allocated at compile time and therefore can be `constexpr`.

The difference in the code generated can be seen at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yo7c8z).

---

**Edit:** OP asks (in effect) can a stack-based variable ever be `constexpr`?  Well, the answer is yes, if *all the members* of that object can be evaluated at compile time.

So, to go back to the original example, when you write:

```
std::initializer_list<int> my_ints {1, 2, 3};
```

a `std::initializer_list` generally consists of a pointer to the underlying array and a length, so, here, the compiler has to push `1`, `2` and `3` onto the stack at runtime, and then put a pointer and a length to that "array" into `my_ints`, so `my_ints` cannot be `constexpr` since the address of said array is not known at compile time.

OTOH, something like:

```
constexpr int i = 42;
```

is fine, since 42 is (obviously) known at compile time and that's all the compiler cares about.

Interestingly:

```
constexpr char s [] = "abcde";
```

also works.  If you look at the [code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/3aYqa4), the compiler allocates "abcde" in static storage and then copies this to `s` at runtime.  Why it doesn't do something similar in the case of `std::initializer_list` is a bit of a mystery (to me, at least).

And finally, why does declaring `my_ints` `static` fix things?  Well, now the compiler can allocate and initialise `1,2,3` at compile time and this "array" now *is* at an address which is known at compile time so `my_ints` can be `constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand: why does declaring the variable `static` suddenly make it work? What would be wrong with a non-`static` `constexpr initializer_list`? I suspect there's some implicit knowledge that I'm missing.

Comment: I thought I'd addressed all that in my answer.  Please perhaps you could read it more carefully.

Comment: @Asker Edited my post.  Hope it helps.